# Integration with payFort react-native-expo

Tags: react-native, expo

**I tried to use payFort with react native expo but it's didn't work so if anyone used it and can help me?**

Answer (score 2):

There is no support available until today for Payfort in react-native in the expo, you have to use `webview` and make API calls manually to authenticate the user and verify the signature and all, I worked on this a few years back and it was a mess.

`So now the solution is to collect the user information in some form and use pay fort rest APIs and make that payment process happen.`